# Is there a way to only print values that are engaged in the final result of the conversion?

Tags: python, datetime, printing, duration, timedelta

Hello my lovely coding friends,
i want to convert this code to only print the values that are actually present in the return.

For example if the input would be

format_duration(125)

desired output:

2 minutes and 5 seconds

in the format that I use i get:

0 years, 0 days, 0 hours, 2 minutes, and 5 seconds

does anyone know a trick how to get rid of the unneeded values in this format?

```
'''code'''

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

###convert seconds to years, days, hours, minutes and seconds

def format_duration(seconds):
    sec = timedelta(seconds=seconds)
    d = datetime(1,1,1,) + sec
    return ("%d years, %d days, %d hours, %d minutes, and %d seconds" % (d.year-1, d.day-1, d.hour, d.minute, d.second))

print(format_duration(125))
```

Comment: strictly speaking you cannot convert an arbitrary duration seconds -> years since different years have different lengths...

Answer (score 1):

Its not the fanciest code, but you can do somethin like this:

```
years, days, hours, minutes, seconds = (d.year - 1, d.day - 1, d.hour, d.minute, d.second)
d_list = [f"{years} years" if years > 0 else None, f"{days} days" if days > 0 else "", f"{hours} hours" if hours > 0 else "", f"{minutes} minutes" if minutes > 0 else "", f"{seconds} seconds" if seconds > 0 else ""]
return ", ".join([s for s in d_list if s])  # joins all strings and discards empty ones
```